# IOS 7 setMaxConcurrentOperationCount >3 causes connection time out in NSOperation subclass

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, nsoperationqueue, nsoperation

i have just ran my twitter application on ios7  from ios6 and discovered something interesting, when setMaxConcurrentOperationCount >3 the requests in the  NSOperation subclass (ConnectOperation) connection: didFial: due to times out. It works perfectly fine in ios6(I can add as many operations I want currently). Please help i am out of ideas!

```
[[[KPOperationsManager sharedOperationsManager]getMessagesDownloadQueue] setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:1];

ConnectOperation  * op= [[ConnectOperation alloc]initWithEndpoint:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json" andParameters:@"YOLO" andAccount:account andMOC:_mngObjSlaveFetchContext1 andDelegate:self];

ConnectOperation  * op2  =[[ConnectOperation alloc]initWithEndpoint:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json" andParameters:@"APPLE" andAccount:account andMOC:_mngObjSlaveContext andDelegate:self];
ConnectOperation  * op3  =[[ConnectOperation alloc]initWithEndpoint:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json" andParameters:@"HOUSE" andAccount:account andMOC:_mngObjSlaveFetchContext2 andDelegate:self];
ConnectOperation  * op4  =[[ConnectOperation alloc]initWithEndpoint:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json" andParameters:@"EDC" andAccount:account andMOC:_mngObjSlaveFetchContext3 andDelegate:self];
ConnectOperation  * op5  =[[ConnectOperation alloc]initWithEndpoint:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json" andParameters:@"IPHONE" andAccount:account andMOC:_mngObjSlaveFetchContext4 andDelegate:self];

[[[OperationsManager sharedOperationsManager]getMessagesDownloadQueue] addOperation:op];
[[[OperationsManager sharedOperationsManager]getMessagesDownloadQueue] addOperation:op2];
[[[OperationsManager sharedOperationsManager]getMessagesDownloadQueue] addOperation:op3];
[[[OperationsManager sharedOperationsManager]getMessagesDownloadQueue] addOperation:op4];
[[[OperationsManager sharedOperationsManager]getMessagesDownloadQueue] addOperation:op5];


@implementation ConnectOperation
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading: (NSURLConnection*) cn
{  //parse data: NEVER GETS HERE IN IOS 7 , ONLY FAILS ; }

- (void) connection: (NSURLConnection*) cn didFailWithError: (NSError*) error
{  NSLog(@"FAILS DUE TO TIME OUT");

- (void)start {
 if( isFinished || [self isCancelled] ) { [self done]; return; }
SLRequest *operation = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET URL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json"] parameters:self.parameters];
[operation setAccount:self.account];
// Use the signed request to start a connection
connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:[operation preparedURLRequest]
                                                delegate:self];
if (![NSThread isMainThread]) {
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(start) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];

    return;
}

[self willChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
isExecuting = YES;
finished = NO;
[self didChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
[self.connection start];
}
```

EDIT:

After further investigation it seems that even when i setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:1 the 4th and 5th(op4, op5) operation still times out! However the first 3 operations runs in serial fashion as expected and retrieves data. Also if i setMaxConcurrentOperationCount>3 none of the operations completes they all time out.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this:

```
// keeps the NSOperation alive for the during of the NSURLConnection!
    [self.downloadConnection scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [self.downloadConnection start];
```

Sorry for being late but I have just started working on IOS. Please let me know if it works.